# Are questions about pools considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion

There seems to be a lot of questions recently about pools.  Generally speaking, are these considered on-topic for the site?  Or is it a matter of specifics?

My thoughts are that questions about pool care (ie: quantities of chemicals to use, how often to run a pump) should be off topic but questions like "How can I install my own heater" (just made that up, not a specific example) should be considered on-topic as they are DIY.

Comment: Do you have any arguments for why they should or should not be on topic?

Comment: Added more details to question with examples.

Comment: There are 31 questions tagged [tag:pool] (most of which remain open), one of the [oldest](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/how-to-keep-pool-water-clean-without-nasty-chemicals) was asked November of 2010. I have no opinion either way, but it appears (at least at a very quick glance) that the community is not opposed to pool questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [What kind of questions can I ask here?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) section of the FAQ we have the following line:

> **Installation, maintenance and repair** of major appliances.

I would say that a swimming pool (or at least the pumps, heaters etc) falls into this category.

I would also say that questions about digging the hole for pool, making it watertight, tiling it, etc. are all on topic - as long as you are doing the job yourself (or at least making the decision whether to do it yourself or employ someone).

Comment: So would [this](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15006/how-long-should-i-run-my-pool-pump-for) be off topic?

Comment: @Steven - hmm, tricky that one.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with the mechanical or chemical maintenance of the equipment.  I disagree with the digging part, especially if the local codes that would be different from other places.  I'm sure there is a big difference in codes in the desert where I live and in Minnesota because of temperatures and earth composition.